# What protocol is used for address mapping in TCP/IPv6?

Tags: networking

does anybody knows what protocol is used for address mapping in TCP/IPv6? im stuck on this question

Answer (score 1):

I think address mapping protocols are same for both IPv4 and IPv6

ARP -Address resolution protocol
RARP - Reverse Address Resolution Protocol